# Microstrip High- and Low-Impedance Short-Line Sections

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microstrip

> Expression 4.50 can be obtained by equating the ABCD parameters of the
>   two circuits ?

How to derive expression 4.50 using the ABCD matrix for [transmission line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCbBX.png) and [π-circuit network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iN0aC.png) ?

Note: Screenshots below are taken from [Microstrip Filters for RF Microwave Applications, 2nd Edition](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=164FD6C83B0A404797EFE084A27712EF)

[image: A]

[image: B]

[image: C]

[image: D]

Comment: It's unclear what it is that you are asking for advice about.

Comment: @Andyaka How to derive expression 4.50 ?

Comment: @Andyaka I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the derivation process for expression 4.50

**ABCD matrix for transmission line at Figure 4.7(a)**

[image: a]

**ABCD matrix for π-circuit network at Figure 4.7(b)**

[image: b]

**Comparing the two ABCD matrices above gives :**

[image: c]

[image: d]

**Applying trigonometry double angle formula :**

[image: e]